# How to align the header title and icon into the center of the header bar in react native navigation

Tags: react-native

**Problem:**

I have created react-native application and in there I have implemented a header with title and icon.In the view, it looks like this.[image]

I want to put place the title and icon in the place of the green dot. I tried lot to find out ways to that but I was could not. This is my code of the top bar.

```
<AssestmentStack.Navigator initialRouteName="assestments">
    <AssestmentStack.Screen
      name="assestments"
      component={ExistingPatientHomeScreen}
      options={(props) => ({
        headerShown: true,
        headerLeft: () => (
          <Icon
            name="align-left"
            size={normalize(20)}
            color="#aaaaaa"
            onPress={() => props.navigation.toggleDrawer()}
          />
        ),
        headerTitleAlign: 'center',
        headerTitle: () => <HeaderTitle title={'Explore'} />,
        headerStyle: {
          backgroundColor: '#f2f2f2',
          height: '35%',
        },
        headerTransparent: false,
        headerLeftContainerStyle: {
          marginLeft: '8%',
        },
        headerStatusBarHeight: 0,
      })}
    />
  </AssestmentStack.Navigator>
```

Can someone help me to find out a way to do this?. If someone can help me to do this.it is really grateful. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disable:

```
      headerStyle: {
          backgroundColor: '#f2f2f2',
          height: '35%',
        },
        headerTransparent: false,
        headerLeftContainerStyle: {
          marginLeft: '8%',
        },
```

Result

```
<AssestmentStack.Navigator initialRouteName="assestments">
    <AssestmentStack.Screen
      name="assestments"
      component={ExistingPatientHomeScreen}
      options={(props) => ({
        headerShown: true,
        headerLeft: () => (
          <Icon
            name="align-left"
            size={normalize(20)}
            color="#aaaaaa"
            onPress={() => props.navigation.toggleDrawer()}
          />
        ),
        headerTitleAlign: 'center',
        headerTitle: () => <HeaderTitle title={'Explore'} />,
        headerStyle: {
          backgroundColor: '#f2f2f2',
        },
      })}
    />
```